# Python Sort List By Number in File Name

Tags: python

I have a bunch of files that are downloaded and I'm trying to get the most recently downloaded version for my analysis. Obviously this is sorting based on text rather than numeric so I'm running into the issue where File 30 comes before File 4. The numbers are within () everytime (your normal copied download). How would I sort based on that number?

Filename (1)
Filename (2)
...
Filename (30)
Filename (4)
...

```
files = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\Filename*")

#files = files.sort(reverse=True)
files = sorted(files, reverse = True)

print(files)
exit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex with pattern `r"\((\d+)\)"` to extract the number inside the brackets and then convert to `int` for sorting.

**Ex:**

```
import re

files = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\Filename*")
files = sorted(files, key=lambda x:int(re.search(r"\((\d+)\)", x).group(1)), reverse = True)
```

Comment: Good answer. Might be helpful to explain the technique you've used, for novices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use key inside the sorted function. They key uses a function that gets the int value between the brackets.

e.g.

```
def get_num(x): 
    return int(x.split('(')[1].lstrip().split(')')[0])

files = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\Filename*")

files = sorted(files, key = get_num, reverse = True)

print(files)
exit()
```